# Source to source manipulations

Tags: c, parsing, linux-kernel, clang

I need to do some source-to-source manipulations in Linux kernel. I tried to use clang for this purpose but there is a problem. Clang does preprocessing of the source code, i.e. macro and include expansion. This causes clang to sometimes produce broken C code in terms of Linux kernel. I can't maintain all the changes manually, since I expect to have thousands of changes per single file.

I tried ANTLR, but the public grammars available are incomplete and not suitable for such projects as Linux kernel.

So my question is the following. Are there any ways to perform source-to-source manipulations for a C code without preprocessing it?

So assume following code.

```
#define AAA 1
void f1(int a){
    if(a == AAA)
        printf("hello");
}
```

After applying source-to-source manipulation I want to get this

```
#define AAA 1
void f1(int a){
    if(functionCall(a == AAA))
        printf("hello");
}
```

But Clang, for instance, produces following code which does not fit my requirements, i.e. it expands macro AAA

```
#define AAA 1
void f1(int a){
    if(functionCall(a == 1))
        printf("hello");
}
```

I hope I was clear enough.

**Edit**

The above code is only an example. The source-to-source manipulations I want to do are not restricted with `if()` statement substitution, but also inserting unary operator in front of expression, replace arithmetic expression with its positive or negative value, etc.

**Solution**

There is one solution I found for my self. I use gcc in order to produce preprocessed source code and then apply Clang. Then I don't have any issues with macro expansion and includes, since that job is done by gcc. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Do your really need to output a source? You can instrument the source while compiling it with clang and you will get binary of instrumented kernel.

Comment: @osgx - I tried this, but I failed at compiling kernel with clang, since there are GCC features, that are not implemented by Clang although llvm folks claims, that they compiled linux kernel with Clang.

Comment: @osgx - Yep, Clang is fresh. I try to update it every few days. I need to use maximum of the kernel, so excluding some parts of the kernel from the build is undesired.

Comment: do you use fresh clang? Some parts of kernel should be turned off to compile kernel with clang (e.g. which uses VLA in middle of the struct as netfilter): here is list http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2010-October/011711.html

Comment: @Sevich: a) I thought you wanted the preprocessor directives preserved; why is your Solution "use GCC to expand them"? b) I thought Clang could invoke the preprocessor by itself [I could be wrong here], why do you need an extra step to invoke gcc?

Comment: @Ira Baxter - a) I wanted to preserve them, since Clang sometimes produces invalid code, because it instantiate directives somehow wrong. If I preprocess source code with GCC, then I don't have that problem anymore. b) Yes, Clang preprocess source code before building AST, but it does not support some GCC extensions. You could look here for more info http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#c_unimpl_gcc

Answer (score 4):

You may consider http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/ : it provides a nice semantics patching framwork.

Comment: How does Coccinelle handle macros and preprocessor directives? The only info I can find at thier website hints "that the C preprocessor can be run by Cocinelle in advance of processing".  That doesn't seem helpful for this.

Answer (score 2):

An idea would be to replace all occurrences of

```
if(a == AAA)
```

with

```
if(functionCall(a == AAA))
```

You can do this easily using, e.g., the sed tool.

If you have a finite collection of patterns to be replaced you can write a sed script to perform the substitution.

Would this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can see it solves my problem only partially. I used `if()` only as example. I can't imagine what pattern should I create in order to insert unary operator in front of expression and how to determine if something is an expression.

Comment: @Sevich - If you can't figure out a pattern to determine whether or not you'll change it, how will you write a program to change it for you? If you can figure out said pattern, sed (or perl, which might be easier/more powerful) will probably do the job.

Comment: @Chris Lutz - I had no such problem with patterns when I was using Clang, but I described Clang issues already.

Comment: Maybe it is not a simple pattern replacement but a more complex manipulation in which you need to recognize some (non-regular) chunk of the input? In this case sed would not be sufficient: you would need to parse the source code. Is this what Clang is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Handling the preprocessor is one of the most difficult problems in applying transformations to C (and C++) code.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) come relatively close to doing this.   DMS can parse C source code, *preserving* most preprocessor conditionals, macro defintions and uses.

It does so by allow preprocessor actions in "well-structured" places.  Examples: #defines are allowed where declarations or statements can occur, macro calls and conditionals as replacements for many of the nonterminals in the language (e.g., function head, expression, statement, declarations) and in many non-structured places that people commonly place them (e.g, #if fooif (...) {#endif).   It parses the source code and preprocessor directives as if they were part of one language (they ARE, its called "C"), and builds corresponding ASTs, which can be transformed and will regenerate correctly with the captured preprocessor directives. [This level of capability handles OP's example perfectly.]

Some directives are poorly placed (both in the syntax sense, e.g., across multiple fragments of the language, and the "you've got to be kidding" understandability sense).  These DMS handles by expanding them away, with some guidance from the advance engineer ("alway expand this macro").  A less satisfactory approach is to hand-convert the unstructured preprocessor conditionals/macro calls into structured ones; this is a bit painful but more workable than one might expect since the bad cases occur with considerably less frequency than the good ones.

To do better than this, one needs to have symbol tables and flow analysis that take into account the preprocessor conditions, and capture all the preprocessor conditionals.   We've done some experimental work with DMS to capture conditional declarations in the symbol table (seems to work fine), and we're just starting work on a scheme for the latter.

Not easy being green.

Comment: Is it under 1000$ for single developer or not?

Comment: sorry but I can't use commercial software.

Comment: @osgx: DMS is an enterprise product.  Prices vary by application and usage.   It is not under $1000.00.  Contact the company for pricing specific to your case.

Comment: @Ira Baxter, You are from Company. Can you say what order is smallest price of DMS for single developer? is it 1000-5000 $ or 5000-10000$ or up to 15000$ or bigger?

Comment: @osgx: Yes, I am.  Pricing varies by your intended use, languages you want to process, and deployment models. (in this sense, pricing is like other enterprise products such as Oracle).  There are DMS licenses that fit across your entire proposed range.  This is the wrong forum for such pricing discussions.  Contact the company.

Answer (score 0):

Clang maintains extremely accurate information about the original source code.

Most notably, the `SourceManager` is able to tell if a given token has been expanded from a macro or written as is, and Chandler Caruth recently implemented macro diagnosis which are able to display the actual macro expansion stack (at the various stages of expansions) tracing back to the actual written code (3.0).

Therefore, it is possible to use the generated AST and then rewrite the source code with all its macros still in place. You would have to query virtually every node to know whether it comes from a macro expansion or not, and if it does retrieve the original code of the expansion, but still it seems possible.

- There is a rewriter module in Clang
- You can dig up Chandler's code on the macro diagnosis stack

So I guess you should have all you need :) (And hope so because I won't be able to help much more :p)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to resort to [Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROSE_(compiler_framework)) framework. [Source](https://github.com/rose-compiler/rose) is available on github.